# Adding a span with a different color isn't actually changing the color

Tags: html, css

I made a small index page and made the logo using text and styling, and added a span to change the color of one of the words but it's not actually changing. I'm not sure why. I made a span with a class of `.highlight` and gave the special `color` to that `.highlight` and even tried adding `!important` but it still isn't working.

This is the page - https://youssefwaelnasr.github.io/hat-manufacturers/ -- the word "Hat" is in a span with the class of `.highlight` that has a different color, but it's not working here.

Here's the GitHub repo with code in it (index.html and css/style.css) - https://github.com/youssefwaelnasr/hat-manufacturers

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is invalid

```
 <span class="highlight"></span>Hat</span> Manufacturers
```

Should be

```
 <span class="highlight">Hat</span> Manufacturers
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry, stupid mistake and I really didn't notice it at all.

Answer (score 1):

In your code at line 17 on your GitHub file (index.html) , the `<span>` tag is not correct.

Replace the **line 17** :

```
<h1><i class="fab fa-redhat"></i> <span class="highlight"> Hat</span> Manufacturers</h1>
```